# How to extend nav-menu-item-control data in Appearance > Customize?

Tags: customization, custom-field, menus, theme-customizer

I have one question as for Nav Menu Items custom fields in the Appearance > Customizer screen.

Since 5.4. there are 2 new hooks:

- `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields` - it works for Appearance > Menus properly and I have added 2 custom fields.
- `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields_customize_template` - it works for Appearance > Customizer and adds HTML properly.

[image]

But I need to use `{{data}}` attribute for getting menu item attributes (my custom e.g. `{{{data.visibility}}}`). I want to put the same 2 custom fields to WP Customizer > Menus > Item section via this hook `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields_customize_template` and use in JS extended `{{{data}}}` object.

There is default `{{data}}` variable in JS template, it looks like this object

[image]

I have added 2 custom fields with custom data for each menu item via this hook `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields` and it works properly.

Is there a way how I can add custom properties for every menu item to `{data}` via PHP (`add_filter`) or JS hooks (`wp.hooks.addFilter`). I don't want to localize script and create another variable and use it in the JS template in `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields_customize_template` hook's callback.

Let me know,
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! I notice you've linked offsite for something in your question, please remove it and embed it directly into WPSE, questions **must** be self contained, it's unnecessary to use an external service for screenshot hosting. I will now edit the question to remove it. I would also adjust the arrow in the image so it's clearer what it's pointing at

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Looks like I just duplicated this as I'm having the exact issue. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372493/add-settings-to-menu-items-in-the-customizer
Did you get anywhere with this? I'm pretty sure you cannot add anything to that `data` object, but via `wp_setup_nav_menu_item` you can get the values into the source code. Just not sure where to go next to fetch that in the JS template renders.